# Update list item in root site when other list's item is updated in subsite

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a "main" list in the root site of site collection and multiple lists ("child") in subsites. When I update (create/update/delete) item in a subsite list I would like to update a item in root site list. I though about event receiver on child list but I wondering if there is a better solution to achieve it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any specific reason you need to do this? seems like you want to create kind of aggregated list at root, which probably can be used for reporting?

Butanyway in order to achieve this it is better to use event receiver.

Comment: Yes, I need aggregation list for reporting

Comment: For aggregation other approach you can do is, export all your list from different site into Excel (this can be any site from different web app as well), this will create connection within excel. Now have a separate excel which combines the data from earlier excel into this using query. Now whenever you want to generate report just refresh this 2 excel file in order:) this is completely OOTB no coding all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I'll use event receiver

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom item event receiver, or a custom workflow is the way to go.
If all child lists can make use of a common content type, then I'd develop the event receiver / workflow to work against this content type